# generate test steps using a file in soapui

Tags: soapui

I've been tasked with testing an email validator tool that is wrapped in a soap api.

To do this, I created a soapui test case that works and set up the assertions I need, but I need to test about 2500 emails that are in a .txt file.

Is there a way to generate a test step for each of these emails easily?

Comment: hello, are you validating the email addresses ? the content of the emails ? to test huge loads it is convenient to use data files, with SOAPUI pro though ...

Comment: I'm calling a service used to validate the email address. I ended up using soupUI pro to do it and used their data source and data source loop

Comment: that's pretty easy with the right tool, a bit expensive though  ;)